# Broadcast receiver throwing error receiving intent in Samsung devices

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

> I am opening fragment on button click of activity as below:

```
private void popFragment() {       
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fl_branch, new BranchFragment());
        ft.commit();
}
```

> Then In java class of fragment I again sent a broadcast event to remove the fragment and resume back to activity as below:

```
private void setListeners() {
        imgCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("REMOVE_FRAGMENT");
                intent.putExtra("branch_address", new Gson().toJson(mList.get(pos)));
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });
}
```

> In the activity I call it in onCreate and receive it as below:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_offer_detail);
        removeFragmentBroadcast();
}

private void removeFragmentBroadcast() {
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("REMOVE_FRAGMENT");
    broadcastReceiverTab = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            //Branch detail
            BranchModel bm = new Gson().fromJson(intent.getStringExtra("branch_address"), BranchModel.class);

            //Change text
            if (bm != null) {
                txtBranchAddress.setText(bm.getLocation());
                txtBranchName.setText(bm.getName());
            }

            //Set new values to offer model
            offerModel.setPhone(bm.getPhone());
            offerModel.setLatitude(bm.getLatitude());
            offerModel.setLongitude(bm.getLongitude());

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                    remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fl_branch)).commit();
            flBranch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };
    context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverTab, intentFilter);
}
```

> And then I unregister the broadcast the event in onDestroy() as below:

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiverTab);
}
```

> But it crashes maximum in Samsung and realme higher-end devices. Any help will be appreciated please.
>
> Crash logs are these two might be different cases:
>
> 1) Crash1

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=REMOVE_FRAGMENT flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.thediscounterapp.activity.VendorDetailActivity$11@6b9934c
android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0
android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0 (LoadedApk.java:1496)    android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run (Unknown Source:2)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7091)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

> 2) Crash2

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException
Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss (FragmentManager.java:2080)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction (FragmentManager.java:2106)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal (BackStackRecord.java:683)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit (BackStackRecord.java:637)
com.thediscounterapp.activity.VendorDetailActivity$11.onReceive (VendorDetailActivity.java:452)
android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0 (LoadedApk.java:1486)   android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run (Unknown Source:2)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7091)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Comment: add the crash log

Comment: higher-end devices means android version? if yes, then mention it.

Comment: Yes Touhidul I have updated crash logs

Comment: Try removing `extras` from `intent` as you are not using it

Comment: Realme Pro 2 Android version 9, Samsung Galaxy J5 and Samsung Galaxy A10

Comment: No, I am using extras. The code is actually like I updated above

Comment: If I understood it correctly, the Runtime Exception was caused by Illegal State Exception. I had the same issue, which was finally resolved by following tips in [this post](https://medium.com/@elye.project/handling-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-d4ee8b630066) . Solutions are written in Kotlin, but I found explanations of why it happens really useful.